# Move decimal point | Lua

Tags: variables, lua

I have a variable

```
a = 1.2345
```

now I want to move the comma position to get

```
a = 123.45
```

How can I achieve this, without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a variable `a` that holds the number `1,2345` (`1.2345`).

The comma (`,`) is used to delimit multiple values in Lua, so in your first example `a` is `1` and `2345` gets discarded and in your second example `a` is `123` and `45` gets discarded.

Lua doesn't support numbers in German locale. If you want a decimal point, use a decimal point (`.`). Your first example was probably intended to be `a = 1.2345` and your second one `a = 123.45`.

Now if you want to move the "comma position" (= "decimal point") right by two positions, that's equivalent to multiplying `a` by `10^2 = 100` in the decimal system:

```lua
a = 1.2345
a = a * 100
print(a) -- 123.45
```

in general, if you want to shift by `n` places in the decimal system:

```lua
a = 1.2345
n = 2

a = a * 10^n

print(a) -- 123.45
```

Comment: @Pxsted if this solved your issue, you might want to accept the answer.